# Laravel Datables Search Include Pivot Table Results

Tags: php, datatables, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

It might be worth mentioning the following information first before I explain what I am trying to do.

I have 3 tables:
 - users
 - vacancies
 - user_vacancy

A vacancy can have an owner which is indicated by the foreign key user_id on the vacancies table.

Many other users can be team members which can be assigned to that same vacancy with the pivot table user_vacancy

I am trying to list all the vacancies for one user in a datatable whether they are the owner or a team member of a vacancy through the Vacancy model, my code looks like this:

**VacanciesController.php:**

```
public function get_user_vacancies() {
    $user = User::find(auth()->id());

    $vacancies = Vacancy::with(['team_members' => function($q) use ($user) {
          $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
    }])->where('user_id', $user->id);

    $dataTables = Datatables::of($vacancies);

    $dataTables->make(true);
}
```

**Vacancy.php:**

```
public function team_members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Access\User\User')->withPivot('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```

**User.php:**

```
public function team_vacancies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vacancy')->withPivot('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```

I understand that I am clearly doing something wrong in order to join the "team member vacancies" with the "owner vacancies" but I am not too sure how to go about getting it right.

I am hoping that someone could possibly assist me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you should add the name of the associated table for both  `team_members` method inside your Models like this :

```
public function team_vacancies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vacancy', 'user_vacancy')->withPivot('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```

and it will be nice to rename your methods by `vacancies` inside `User.php` and `teams` inside `Vacancy.php`

Comment: Hi Thamer, thanks for your response, I will keep those last few tips in mind.

I have also tried it with - return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Access\User\User', 'user_vacancy', 'vacancy_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

For some reason it will not return the vacancies where the user is a team member on but only the vacancies where the user is the owner of the vacancy. 

For example if there are 40 vacancies where the user is the owner and there are 6 vacancies where the user is a team member, it will only retrieve 40 results instead of 46 results.